# How to Use Git Archive to Create a Tarball on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, bash

In Git Bash I've tried to use this command:

```
$ git archive -o test.tar.gz master
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
```

The file `test.tar.gz` is empty, but my repository is not empty and creating a zip file works fine (contains all my source files)! Why does the tarball format fail to produce an archive?

Comment: Do you have both `tar` and `gzip` in your `$PATH`? Try `which tar` and `which gzip`. I'm not sure that Git bundles these tools, and Windows definitely doesn't ship them.

Comment: `tar` and `gzip` appear to be installed. I think they are bundled in the Git Bash installation. These are the versions I have: `gzip 1.2.4 (18 Aug 93)`, `tar (GNU tar) 1.22`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a compatibility problem between the way `git archive` wants to pipe content from `tar` to `gzip` and the way Windows handles pipes. You can generate the same error message by piping `tar` into `gzip` manually:

```
$ tar -c file.txt | gzip
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
```

These two commands work for me on Windows 7, and should be functionally identical to the one you're trying:

```
$ git archive -o test.tar master
$ gzip test.tar
```

Answer (score 3):

Pipe it to gzip:

```
git archive master | gzip > test.tar.gz
```

Comment: Any explanation why that works and not `git archive -o test.tar.gz master`?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are not using Git Bash, from regular Command Prompt you can just:

```
git archive --format=tar.gz master > test.tar.gz
```